# What is the meaning of "Family only runs so deep" and "Dysfunctional sense" from the conversation given down below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*Here's part of the conversation from vampire diaries*

Zach: I'm full of vervain. I've been putting it in my coffee for 16 years.

Damon: So it was your vervain. Good for you. **Family only runs so deep, huh?**

Zach: We are not family, Damon. Only in the most **dysfunctional sense**. In fact, I avoided having a living, breathing, loving family because of you.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret 'family only runs so deep' to mean that each adult, when he grows up, has to decide which part of his upbringing to keep: the things that his family did, will he do them? With the idea that he will not be keeping all of them.

'Only in the most dysfunctional sense' would mean that their relationship is far from the normal 'family'. I don't know the plot, but it could well be that they aren't biological family at all, but do tend to hang around each other and depend on each other a little bit like a family might do.